# Is anyway to prove this: $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k})< (1/n^n)*(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sqrt{1+a_{k}*a_{k+1}}))^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms, binomial-coefficients, products

$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}
<
{1 \over n^{n}}\left(\,\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\,\sqrt{1+a_{k}\,a_{k+1}\,}\,\right)^n
$$

ak and n are positive real number greater than 0.

EDIT:  a_{k+1} becomes a_{1} when a_{k}=a_{n}, it is a cylic notation. SORRY.

Any ideas of how to attack the problem??
Thank You.

I don't know if this could help, but the 1/n is also the exponent for the left hand side. I'm thinking maybe of log??

I'm pretty sure that at some point it would be helpful the binominal coefficent?? I don't know.

Comment: What are $a_k$ and $x_k$?

Comment: I correct it, x is just a, problem solved.

Comment: But what is $a_k$? Just any real number? (not all $a_i$ will make the square root on the right well defined)

Comment: To attack the problem, the first is to figure out what are the allowed ranges of $a_k$. Since there is a square root, it might make sense to assume all $a_k > 0$. However, $a_k$ cannot be arbitrary big. This is because if you scale everything by a big $\lambda$, the LHS growth as $\lambda^n$ while the RHS growth as $\lambda^2$ only. This means the inequality will fail for large enough $a_k$. Back to square one, what is your $a_k$?

Comment: ak is a real number

Comment: I corrected a very big mistake, sorry :(.

Comment: 2 becomes a n, now is corrected.

Comment: Is there really a $a_{n+1}$ in your inequality?

Comment: @achillehui It likely is cyclic notation, so $a_{n+1} = a_1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin this is also what I suspect but it will be better to wait for confirmation from OP.

Comment: You need to correct the title as well as the text. You need also to specify a range for the $a_k$, and say what $a_{n+1}$ means, as requested in earlier comments.

Comment: Yes!, sorry, you are right in a(n) the a(n+1) becomes a(1)

Answer (score 1):

After the question get cleared up, the answer becomes a trivial application of GM $\le$ AM.
Since the $a_k$ are in cyclic notation. i.e. $a_{n+1} = a_1$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n a_k 
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k a_k}
= \sqrt{a_1}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{a_k a_{k+1}}\right)\sqrt{a_n}\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k a_{k+1}} \quad\color{blue}{\longleftarrow a_{1} = a_{n+1} \text{ and rearrange }}\\
&\le\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k a_{k+1}}}{n}\right)^n
\quad\color{blue}{\longleftarrow \text{GM} \le \text{AM}}\\
&< \left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+a_k a_{k+1}}}{n}\right)^n
= \frac{1}{n^n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+a_k a_{k+1}}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's very nice! +1